# IgniteRDD saveValues too slow

Tags: ignite

We are trying to create Ignite RDD from Spark rdd as below

```
def storeDataframeInCache(sc: SparkContext, rdd: RDD[Row]): Unit ={
var igniteContext: IgniteContext[String, Row] =  new IgniteContext[String, Row](sc, () => IgniteConfig.getIgniteConf(true), false)
var igniteRDD = igniteContext.fromCache("rdd")
igniteRDD.saveValues(rdd)
}
```

Here saveValues takes too much time.

Is there a better possible way of doing this?

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Is it possible for you to populate Ignite RDD or a cache directly without creating a Spark RDD? It shold work faster.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Denis. We use spark Dataframe for transformations and actions. At the last step we need to store the Spark Dataframe as IgniteRDD. For this we are getting Spark RDD from Spark Dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

There may be different reasons for a poor performance. You should figure out whether the problem is in Spark or Ignite and start optimizing the slow one.

Cache performance strongly depends on its configuration. The more copies of the same data is stored on the cluster, the slower it will work. If you want the cache to work fast, you should choose partitioned mode over replicated and disable backups. Persistence also may negatively affect cache's performance. You may refer documentation for more information: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/performance-tips